# Relaunch app when resuming from background

Tags: android

Can I prevent app from resuming when it's killed by other process?

I have problem where I have `Singleton` class instance in `Application class`, it holds through app all my info about user and stuff gathered from `API`. When I open app from background(if it's killed by some process) I getting `null` on User Model(Picture paths, Name...) and app crushes.

Best way for me is app relaunch from launcher screen and get all info again, not resuming. Any solution for this?

Comment: Can you show how do you use UserModel inside  recreating Activity/Fragment?

Comment: All sections under https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/index.html

Answer (score 0):

> Can I prevent app from resuming when it's killed by other process?

There are three ways an app can be "resumed", by a call to either **`onCreate`**, **`onStart`**, or **`onResume`**. Which one is called depends on how your app was "suspended", and what happens to it while in this state.

**`onResume`** follows **`onPause`**, which occurs when another app is brought to the foreground.

**`onStart`** (**`onRestart`**) follows **`onStop`**, which occurs when your app is no longer visible.

**`onCreate`** follows **`onPause`** or **`onStop`** if your memory is lost to another app.

> When I open app from background(if it's killed by some process) I
>   getting Nulls on User Model(Picture paths, Name...)

Try persisting this user data in **`onSaveInstanceState`**

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString(STATE_USER, mUser);
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and restoring it in either **`onCreate`** or **`onRestoreInstanceState`**

```
static final String STATE_USER = "user";
private String mUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore user data from saved state
        mUser = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_USER);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    text.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_USER));
}
```